# Loop through rows and select dynamic range of columns to edit

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through a variable number of rows, searching for a value in Column E (i.e."WLO"). When I find a row with "WLO" in Column E I want to select the cells in that row from Column J until the end of the data in that row. The number of columns populated after Column J will vary as this is used in multiple spreadsheets so the selection to the right needs to be dynamic. I want to do something like the below code but currently it turns every row between the first instance of WLO to the last instance of WLO red, even if there are rows with other values in between. [See Screenshot of current results here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFtcy.png)

```
Sub Color_row()
   Dim EndRow As Long
   Dim e As Long

   EndRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For e = 2 To EndRow
    If (Range("E" & e).Value = "WLO") Then
      Range("J" & e, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
  Next e

End Sub
```

[This is an example of I would like to be able to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLhR4.png)
Thanks for any advice. It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first create an end range. You were close!

```
Sub Color_row()
   Dim EndRow As Long
   Dim e As Long
   Dim EndCol, StartCol As Range

   EndRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For e = 2 To EndRow
    If (Range("E" & e).Value = "WLO") Then
        Set EndCol = Range("J" & e).End(xlToRight)
        Set StartCol = Range("J" & e)
        Range(StartCol, EndCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
  Next e

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Then clause, the Selection is wherever your active cell is, so it will highlight to that row. Change the Selection to be your start point, which is J and the row number.

```
Sub Color_row()
   Dim EndRow As Long
   Dim e As Long

   EndRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For e = 2 To EndRow
    If (Range("E" & e).Value = "WLO") Then
      Range("J" & e, Range("J" & e).End(xlToRight)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
  Next e

End Sub
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!